# How to optimize pixel editing in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, pixel-manipulation

I try to mae some picture animation in JavaScript cnavas, so I have to manipulate with pixels, but the problem is that walking array of pixel takesa lot of time, the native functions of context do it much faster.

This test shows it:

```
    <canvas width="600" height="400" id="canvas"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");
// Test 1
var date1 = new Date();
ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
// Test 2
var date2 = new Date();
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 600, 400);
var i, j, p;
for(i = 100; i < 300; ++i)
    for(j = 100; j < 300; ++j) {
        p = (i * 600 + j) * 4;
        imageData.data[p] = 0;
        imageData.data[p + 1] = 0;
        imageData.data[p + 2] = 0;
        imageData.data[p + 3] = 255;
    }
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
// Test 3
var date3 = new Date();
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(100, 100, 200, 200);
var i, j, p;
for(i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
    for(j = 0; j < 200; ++j) {
        p = (i * 200 + j) * 4;
        imageData.data[p] = 0;
        imageData.data[p + 1] = 0;
        imageData.data[p + 2] = 0;
        imageData.data[p + 3] = 255;
    }
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 100, 100);
var date4 = new Date();

alert("fillRect: " + (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) + "\ngetImageData(full): " + (date3.getTime() - date2.getTime()) + "\ngetImageData(part): " + (date4.getTime() - date3.getTime()));
</script>
```

The approximate results are: 0, 14, 12.

Why does it happens? What is the fastest way to change pixels manualy?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: [Faster Canvas Pixel Manipulation with Typed Arrays](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/12/faster-canvas-pixel-manipulation-with-typed-arrays/)

And [here](http://jsperf.com/canvas-pixel-manipulation) you can run the benchmark yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for links, I will explore

Comment: @stewe, `TypeError: Object # has no method 'set'.`

Comment: You'll need to see if your browser/build is new enough (and configured appropriately) to support the required language/HTML5 features.

Comment: It's sad, but it works neither in new Opera, nor in new Chrome. Only in Firefox.